# ERRO #1111 - Invalid use of group function (SUM | COUNT)

Tags: mysql, sql

Esta *query* dá-me o total de presenças de dois grupos parlamentares (e.g: PS, PSD) entre duas datas:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.partido, 

(SELECT COUNT(presencas.assiduidade) FROM presencas, reunioes
 WHERE presencas.assiduidade = 'Presença (P)' 
 AND presencas.id_deputado = a.id_deputado 
 AND reunioes.data_reuniao BETWEEN '2015-10-23' AND '2017-08-30' 
 AND presencas.id_reuniao = reunioes.id_reuniao) AS total_presencas

FROM deputados a WHERE a.partido IN ('PS','PSD');
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No entanto, queria somar o total de presenças por grupo parlamentar (e.g: PS, PSD) entre datas, mas a seguinte query dá-me erro:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.partido, 

(SELECT SUM(COUNT(presencas.assiduidade)) FROM presencas, reunioes
 WHERE presencas.assiduidade = 'Presença (P)' 
 AND presencas.id_deputado = a.id_deputado 
 AND reunioes.data_reuniao BETWEEN '2015-10-23' AND '2017-08-30' 
 AND presencas.id_reuniao = reunioes.id_reuniao) as total_presencas

FROM deputados a WHERE a.partido IN ('PS','PSD');
```

Penso que este erro deve-se ás duas funções juntas SUM | COUNT.

> 1111 - Invalid use of group function

Podem ajudar-me?
A minha intenção é fazer algo como:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não seria fazer um Sum de `assiduidade` agrupado por `partido` e `assiduidade`?

Comment: Só faltou você colocar o `group by`.

Answer (score 4):

As funções de agrupamento como `COUNT`, `SUM`, `AVG`... dentre tantas outras, devem ser utilizadas com agrupamento de dados utilizando-se da cláusula `GROUP BY`, e tu não estás utilizando para definir como será o agrupamento e a contagem dos valores.

No teu caso, precisas de algo como:

```
SELECT deputados.partido, SUM(presencas.assiduidade) AS presenca
FROM deputados
JOIN presencas ON (presencas.id_deputado = deputados.id_deputado )
JOIN reunioes ON (presencas.id_reuniao = reunioes.id_reuniao)
WHERE presencas.assiduidade = 'Presença (P)' 
AND reunioes.data_reuniao BETWEEN '2015-10-23' AND '2017-08-30' 
AND deputados.partido IN ('PS','PSD')
GROUP BY deputados.partido
```

PS: Ao efetuar junções, dê preferência à utilização explícita de `JOINs`, deixe a cláusula `WHERE` para a filtragem necessária dos dados.